# file-roller doesn't use single-click anymore?

Tags: file-roller

In the old days, I can navigate in file-roller with only single click, now I had to do a double click, anyone know if this is configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's because as of v. 2.91.91 [`File-Roller` follows `Nautilus` "click policy"](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/ftp-release-list/2011-March/msg00042.html). This however, required `Nautilus` gsettings schema (for the click policy) meaning `Nautilus` had to be present on the system. Back then (v. 3.0), `File-Roller` crashed on systems where Nautilus was missing (i.e. `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` was not present) so the devs decided to fix the issue by [falling back to `double-click`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649094).